# How do I determine which contact a timeline item was shared to?

Tags: google-mirror-api

I am writing an app using the mirror api and I need to be able to share an image that gets associated on the server side with a specific user. I inserted two contacts via my glassware and I can share images to each contact. On the server end I get something back like this but there is no reference to the contact id that it was shared to?

```
{
 u'itemId': u'e2de58b4-e281-4518-8312-948159167be8', # id to image?
 u'userToken': u'6b037418-9a7d-4137-943e-2b857f960a80', # user who shared?
 u'operation': u'INSERT',
 u'collection': u'timeline',
 u'userActions': [{u'type': u'SHARE'}]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you request the timeline item with the specified `itemId` with a `timeline.get` request, the item will have a `recipients` property that includes information about which contact it has been shared with, and an `attachments` property with information about the shared photo itself.

See the according documentation here: https://developers.google.com/glass/subscriptions#shared_picture

Comment: Ahh I see. Thanks for the link. The Mirror API documentation is a little tricky to navigate sometimes. I wonder why they don't just pass the timeline item data along with the subscription post? Seems like a waste to me

Comment: The reason for not pasting the data directly is to prevent an unauthorized endpoint to retrieve it: a developer could have made a mistake in the subscription or the user might have revoked access shortly after the notification was sent.